# "maintains his army had to buy the mortars"

Tags: word-meaning, ambiguity, parsing

Source: *[Putin's 'Gunman' Demanding More Russian Support in Ukraine](http://www.newsmax.com/Newsfront/vladimir-putin-ukraine-separatist-militia/2014/07/25/id/584967/)*

> Further, the ministry insists that Strelkov's troops got all the weapons they needed from Russia, but Strelkov **maintains his army** had to buy the mortars, rocket launchers, and other weapons "for fabulously huge money"

I don't understand how the clause **maintains his army** fits in with **Strelkov** and **had to buy**. Wouldn't it be better to say ***Strelkov to maintain his army had to buy...***? Clarify the grammar for me, please.

Comment: Try inserting a *that* in between *maintains* and *his army*, and you might find that it's much easier to understand.

Comment: I'm not an English major, but I interpret this as `Strelkov has said before, and continues to say that he had to buy the mortars, rocket launchers, and other weapons`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Maintain* is used here in the sense defined in [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/maintain?showCookiePolicy=true), 4:

> **verb** *(transitive)*
>   [...]
>   4. *(takes a clause as object)* to state or assert   ⇒ *he maintained that Talbot was wrong*

*Maintains* parallels *insists* in the first clause: The ministry says that, but Strelkov says this.